# Discord.js command that deletes bot messages and user commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

## Hi,

I'm having trouble creating a command that will delete a bot message and user commands,

-User commands such as if it starts with a prefix "!"

-and the bot messages in general.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Discord.js [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Client) is your friend. The class `Client` has event [`Message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Message) which is triggered whenever someone sends a message. The message has property `.author`, which itself has the property `.bot`, which is a `boolean`.

To find whether the message starts with a given prefix, you can compare the prefix to the string returned from the message property `.content`.

If you want to delete a given message, don't worry. The class has also the method [`delete`](http://Discord.js%20%5Bdocumentation%5D%5B1%5D%20is%20your%20friend.%20The%20class%20%60Client%60%20has%20event%20%5B%60Message%60%5D%5B2%5D%20which%20is%20triggered%20whenever%20someone%20sends%20a%20message.%20The%20message%20has%20property%20%60.author%60,%20which%20itself%20has%20the%20property%20%60.bot%60,%20which%20is%20a%20%60boolean%60.%20%20To%20find%20whether%20the%20message%20starts%20with%20a%20given%20prefix,%20you%20can%20compare%20the%20prefix%20to%20the%20string%20returned%20from%20the%20message%20property%20%60.content%60%20%20%20%20%20%5B1%5D:%20https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Client%20%20%20%5B2%5D:%20https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Message).

Using these, you should have all the needed tools for what you asked.